# Largest_at_point function

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, rectangles

Have a hard time trying to find all the possible rectangle values for the following function.

```
def largest_at_position(matrix: list[list[int]], row: int, col: int) -> int:
    """
    Returns the area of the largest rectangle whose top left corner is at
    position <row>, <col> in <matrix>.

    You MUST make use of the helper <longest_chain> here as you loop through
    each row of the matrix. Do not modify (i.e., mutate) the input matrix.

    >>> case1 = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    ...          [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    ...          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    ...          [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
    >>> largest_at_position(case1, 0, 0)
    4
    >>> largest_at_position(case1, 2, 0)
    5
    >>> largest_at_position(case1, 1, 2)
    6
    """
```

Here is the code for longest chain helper function

```
def longest_chain(lst: List[int]) -> int:
    chain = 0
    lst2 = lst.copy()
    while chain < len(lst) and lst2[0] == 1:
        chain += 1
        lst2.pop(0)
    return chain
```

and here's my code so far which returns all the numbers from the the starting point's column to the end of the row

```
def largest_at_position(matrix, row, col):
  nlist = []
  columns = len(matrix[0])
  i = row
  chain = longest_chain(matrix[i])
  
  while i < len(matrix):
    for j in range(col, columns):
      nlist.append(matrix[i][j])
    i += 1
  #nlist = nlist[::columns]
  return nlist
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (keep a variable of minimum row area that still form a rectangle):

```py
def largest_at_position(matrix: list[list[int]], row: int, col: int) -> int:
    i, current = 0, None
    while i + row < len(matrix):
        row_area = longest_chain(matrix[row + i][col:])
        if row_area == 0:
            break
        elif current is None:
            current = row_area
        elif row_area >= current:
            current = min(row_area, current)
        else:
            break
        i += 1
    return (current or 0) * i


def longest_chain(lst: list[int]) -> int:
    chain = 0
    lst2 = lst.copy()
    while chain < len(lst) and lst2[0] == 1:
        chain += 1
        lst2.pop(0)
    return chain


case1 = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

print(largest_at_position(case1, 0, 0))
print(largest_at_position(case1, 2, 0))
print(largest_at_position(case1, 1, 2))
```

Prints:

```
4
5
6
```